# Visual Studio 2010 does't give any error when there is any garbage after #include<file.h> in the same line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c++, c

I found this by accident.
If you add any garbage after 
`#include <file.h>` in the same line, for e.g.

```
#include <myheaderfile.h> something something type anything here
```

and compile/build, Visual Studio 2010 doesn't give any errors.
Why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's undefined behaviour, but the compiler might give you a warning (e.g., GCC: `extra tokens at end of #include directive`).

Comment: Pay attention to warnings: `warning C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline`

Comment: And if you really want the wraning to be an error use [#pragma warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(v=vs.110).aspx) or [/WX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/thxezb7y(v=vs.110)) to make C4067 nto an error

Comment: @Hans Passant, @Frank Boyne. Thanks. `#pragma warning` was useful.